# Multi-class image classification model has high test accuracy but low prediction confidence

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

TL;DR: Although my model is predicting correct classes, it is not very confident about those correct predictions.

My dataset contains 32x32-sized images for 46 classes. I have trained a Deep Convolutional Neural Network which is giving me a high class prediction accuracy (~98.8%) and F1 score (also above 98%). However, when I observe the softmax probabilities that my model assigns to each of the 46 classes, I see that the correct class only has a probability of around 0.057 while the other 45 classes have a probability of around 0.02.

**Why this could be happening and how I can improve my model to predict with high confidence?**

Model architecture:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 rescaling (Rescaling)       (None, 32, 32, 1)         0         
                                                                 
 conv2D_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 28, 28, 32)        832       
                                                                 
 batch_normalization (BatchN  (None, 28, 28, 32)       128       
 ormalization)                                                   
                                                                 
 max_pool_1 (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 14, 14, 32)        0         
                                                                 
 conv2D_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 10, 10, 64)        51264     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_1 (Batc  (None, 10, 10, 64)       256       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 max_pool_2 (MaxPooling2D)   (None, 5, 5, 64)          0         
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 5, 5, 64)          0         
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 1600)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 128)               204928    
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_2 (Batc  (None, 128)              512       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_3 (Batc  (None, 64)               256       
 hNormalization)                                                 
                                                                 
 output (Dense)              (None, 46)                2990      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 269,422
Trainable params: 268,846
Non-trainable params: 576
```